# How to change font style, size and color in xaringan slide

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, xaringan

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do the change of **font size**, **colour** and **style** (bold, italic, etc.) for ***particular*** words or phrases in individual `xaraingan` slides within `rmarkdown`.

The following is my code:

```
---
title: "Econ"
subtitle: "Week 1"
author: "Instructor"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    
---

# Is economics a science?

--
Probably not, maybe pseudo-science?.
```

I want to make "pseudo-science" ***bold, italicized, red, slightly bigger***.

Comment: Can you provide some code (I mean what you have tried so far?), it will really help us to help you.

Comment: Please see the revised post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To style certain lines or phrases, you need to define your own [content class](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-format.html#content-classes) (say `.my-style`) using CSS and wrap those lines or phrases with that content class (like `.my-style[lines or phrases]`) and define CSS rules for styles that you want to use in CSS file `styles.css`. Then attach that CSS file by specifying it in the YAML key `css:` along with other style files.

```
---
title: "Econ"
subtitle: "Week 1"
author: "Instructor"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    
---

# Is economics a science?

--
Probably not, maybe .my-style[pseudo-science]?.
```

**styles.css**

```
.my-style {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am pretty new. Could you tell me where to write and store `styles.css` file and how to create `styles.css` file?

Comment: you can create css file from Rstudio by following `File > New File > CSS file` and save it at the same place where your Rmarkdown file is saved.